# Twython with 140 character limitation of twitter

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, social-networking, twython

I am trying to search in twitter using Tython, but it seems that the library has a limitation on 140 characters. With the new feature of python, i.e. 280 characters length, what can one do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a limitation of Twython. The Twitter API by default returns the old 140-character limited tweet. In order to see the newer extended tweet you just need to supply this parameter to your search query:

`tweet_mode=extended`

Then, you will find the 280-character extended tweet in the `full_text` field of the returned tweet.

I use another library ([TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)), but I think you would do something like this using Twython:

```
results = api.search(q='pizza',tweet_mode='extended')
for result in results['statuses']:
    print(result['full_text'])
```

Comment: No, it does work for RTs too. RTs are embedded as an entire tweet object inside the `retweeted_statusus` field. So, you will find the 280-character text in this object also in the `full_text` field.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am unable to find anything related "Tython". However, if searching twitter data (in this case posts) and/or gathering metadata is your goal, I would recommend you having a look into the library [TwitterSearch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TwitterSearch).

Here is a quick example from the provided link with searching for Twitter-posts containing the words `Gutenberg` and `Doktorarbeit`.

```
from TwitterSearch import *
try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder() # create a TwitterSearchOrder object
    tso.set_keywords(['Guttenberg', 'Doktorarbeit']) # let's define all words we would like to have a look for
    tso.set_language('de') # we want to see German tweets only
    tso.set_include_entities(False) # and don't give us all those entity information

    # it's about time to create a TwitterSearch object with our secret tokens (API auth credentials)
    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = 'aaabbb',
        consumer_secret = 'cccddd',
        access_token = '111222',
        access_token_secret = '333444'
     )

     # this is where the fun actually starts :)
    for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
        print( '@%s tweeted: %s' % ( tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'] ) )
except TwitterSearchException as e: # take care of all those ugly errors if there are some
    print(e)
```