# How to get the full text from streaming tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, streaming

When i run my code *i only get the text of the tweet with dots*. How can i get the full text of the tweet.  This is my code and the output is below.

```
class TwitterAuthenticator():
    def authenticate_twitter_app(self):
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        return auth

class TwitterStreamer():
    """
        Class for streaming and processing live tweets.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.twitter_authenticator = TwitterAuthenticator()
    def stream_tweets(self, fetched_tweets_filename, hash_tag):
        # This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
        listener = TwitterListener(fetched_tweets_filename)
        auth = self.twitter_authenticator.authenticate_twitter_app()
        # api = tweepy.API(auth)


        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth,listener)
        stream.filter(track = hash_tag)


class TwitterListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    """
    This is a basic listener class that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """

def __init__(self, fetched_tweets_filename):
    self.fetched_tweets_filename = fetched_tweets_filename

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
            json_load = json.loads(data)
            text = json_load['text']
            tf.write(text)
            tf.write('\n')
            #tf.write(json.dumps(text))
            #tf.write(data)
        return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
    return True

def on_status(self, status):
    print(status.text)

def on_error(self, status):
    if status == 420:
        # Returning False on_data method in case rate limit occurs.
        return False
    print(status.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = ["@Uber"]
    fetched_tweets_filename = "tweets.txt"

twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(fetched_tweets_filename,user)
```

The Output is as follows.

> RT @lexaa_24: EVERYONE IN ROCHESTER DO NOT GET INTO AN UBER WITH THIS MAN! He seemed intoxicated, was swerving, did not follow directions o…

How can i get the full text without dots to save in my text file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That is 140 characters

Comment: I need to get the complete tweet without dots @sshashank124

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391092/twython-with-140-character-limitation-of-twitter